# SELECT only one entry of multiple occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a Table that looks like this:

```
id fk value
------------
1  1  'lorem'
2  1  'ipsum'
3  1  'dolor'
4  2  'sit'
5  2  'amet'
6  3  'consetetur'
7  3  'sadipscing'
```

Each **fk** can appear multiple times, and for each **fk** I want to select the last row (or more precise the row with the respectively highest id) – like this:

```
id fk value
------------
3  1  'dolor'
5  2  'amet'
7  3  'sadipscing'
```

I thought I could use the keyword `DISTINCT` here like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, fk, value 
FROM table
```

but I am not sure on which row `DISTINCT` will return and it must be the last one.
Is there anything like (*pseudo*)

```
SELECT id, fk, value 
FROM table 
WHERE MAX(id) 
FOREACH DISTINCT(fk)
```

I hope I am making any sense here :)
thank you for your time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table  
  WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP BY fk)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.fk, a.value
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(a.id) id, a.fk FROM tableA a GROUP BY a.fk
           ) AS b ON a.fk = b.fk AND a.id = b.id;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.id, a.fk, a.value
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.fk, a.value FROM tableA a ORDER BY a.fk, a.id DESC) AS a 
GROUP BY a.fk;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM
table1 t
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(id) as id
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY fk
) t1
ON t.id = t1.id
```

Inner query will give you highest id for each fk using `MAX()`. Then we join this inner table with your main table.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
SELECT id, fk, value FROM table GROUP BY fk HAVING id = MAX(id)
```

I don't have mysql here, but it works in Sybase ASE

Comment: I tried your suggestion on my MySQL database but 0 rows are returned. But thanks for pointing out the keyword 'HAVING', it certainly will be useful in my future queries